# TensorFlow: Training and Testing in the same Session

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to train and test my model in the same TensorFlow session. I use two different `tf.FIFOQueue`s to load the training and test data using multiple threads (since `feed_dict` leads to poor performance). I tried two things:

1. I tried creating my model twice (for training and testing) with shared parameters. But I was using `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` and it does not allow to share the parameters of batch normalization.
2. I tried to condition the input `tf.FIFOQueue` of my network on `is_training` boolean placeholder using `tf.cond` but apparently `tf.cond` executes both `tf.FIFOQueue`s dequeue function, no matter what `is_training` holds.

I was wondering what the conventional setup is to train and test in the same session without using `feed_dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` **does** allow to share batch normalization parameters if defined in a global `tf.variable_scope`.

**Example Code:** Taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1122).

```
def model(data, is_training=False, reuse=None, scope='my_model'):
  # Define a variable scope to contain all the variables of your model
  with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'model', data, reuse=reuse):
    ....
    net = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(net, is_training)
   return net

train_outputs = model(train_data, is_training=True)
eval_outputs = model(eval_data, is_training=False, reuse=True)
```